# How do I test a modal component using the new HTML popover API

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, testing, jestjs

I am bulding a modal component using HTML new [popover API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Popover_API), the way I used to build modals in react was something like this:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Modal = ({ isOpen, onClose, children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {isOpen && (
        <div className="modal-overlay">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <span className="close-button" onClick={onClose}>
              X
            </span>
            {children}
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default Modal;
```

And I used to test them like this:

```js
  it('renders modal when isOpen is true', () => {
    const { getByText } = render(
      <Modal isOpen={true} onClose={() => {}}>
        <p>Modal Content</p>
      </Modal>
    );
    const modalContent = getByText('Modal Content');
    expect(modalContent).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  it('does not render modal when isOpen is false', () => {
    const { queryByText } = render(
      <Modal isOpen={false} onClose={() => {}}>
        <p>Modal Content</p>
      </Modal>
    );
    const modalContent = queryByText('Modal Content');
    expect(modalContent).toBeNull();
  });
```

But now with the new popover API this tests no longer works, as they are always on the document, and visible, somehow the browser pushes the content to the front so it becomes the focus in the screen when the popover is open but I don't see how can I test components using this new API.

IMO as it is something handled by the browser I shouldn't test it, but there are some cases where I need my popover to show when the page is loaded, and I can't see any property that the modal has, to let me know that it is opened or not.

The only workaround in my head is using the dom to find the `:popover-open` pseudo selector, if the modal has this selector is opened, if not it is hidden. But I wanted to be sure that there is no other option.

This api should have some property in the dom to know its current state.

Comment: When you say "as they are always on the document, and visible..." do you mean visible in the DOM tree or visible as in rendered in the window and cannot be closed at all? Have you explored `toBeVisible` yet? https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tobevisible